# Linear Algebra math

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be the set of all vectors of the form $[5s,5s+3t,3s-5t,5t]$ Show that $W$ is a subspace of set of 4 real numbers by finding vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $$W=\text{span}\{u​,v​\}.$$

What does this imply about​ $W$?

A. $W=\text{span}\{s,t\}$

B. $W=\text{span}\{u,v\}$

C. $W=u+v$

D. $W=s+t$

Explain how this result shows that W is a subspace of set of real numbers R4.

Comment: Kindly include your attempt, describing where you are stuck.

Comment: i couldn't figure out how to approach this question

Comment: B is the same as your definition of $W$. So that is just reflexivity of equality. Are you sure you copied the choices correctly?

Comment: yes that's what the question is

Comment: What is real numbers 4? Do you mean $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Create vectors $u$ and $v$: pick (simple) values for $s$, $t$

$$(s,t) = (1,0) \implies u = \left[\begin{matrix}{\phantom{-}\,0\\\phantom{-}\,3\\-5\\\phantom{-}\,1}\end{matrix}
\right]$$

$$(s,t) = (0,1) \implies v = \left[\begin{matrix}{5\\5\\3\\0}\end{matrix}
\right]$$

#### Conclusion

$$
W = \text{span}
\left( 
\left[\begin{matrix}{\phantom{-}\,0\\\phantom{-}\,3\\-5\\\phantom{-}\,1}
\end{matrix}\right] ,
\left[\begin{matrix}{5\\5\\3\\0}
\end{matrix}\right]
\right)
$$

#### Review choices

A. Won't work. The variables $s$ and $t$ are scalars, not 4 vectors.

B. Obvious choice. Restatement of premise.

C. Won't work. Combination of scalars.

D. Won't work. Is a vector, not a vector space. Spans imply vector space.